# Removing additional password field from ssh login on Ubuntu 20

Tags: ssh, password, yubikey

[image: SSH Screenshot]

I just bought a Yubikey a few days back. I have tried to use the key to login to SSL without a password. I have it working, but it displays an error and shows interactive auth prompts.

The only real prompts are the customer and Yubikey one. How can I remove lines 2-4?